# rows overlapping in CSS Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

How can I prevent the footer row from overlapping the content row?

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

```css
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 3.7rem auto auto;
 grid-template-columns: 3rem 3fr 2fr;
}
*[role="banner"] {
 grid-row: 1;
 grid-column: 2/4;
 
 background-color: green;
 height: 3rem;
}
*[role="main"] {
 grid-row: 2;
 grid-column: 2;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100px;
}
*[role="contentinfo"] {
 grid-row: 3;
 grid-column: 2/3;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
}
*[role="contentinfo"] img {
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div role="banner"></div>
<article role="main"><p>Some Text.</p><p>Some more text</p><p>the last text</p></article>
<footer role="contentinfo"><img src="https://s14-eu5.ixquick.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.motor-talk.de%2Fdata%2Fgalleries%2F0%2F147%2F9424%2F43109894%2Fbild--7008737403287221413.jpg&sp=6a4eaf3bd8ff58ca9d9bba2e3519888e"></footer>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The footer (row 3) is overlapping the article (row 2) because you have a fixed height on the article:

```
[role="main"] { height: 100px; }
```

The overrides the `auto` height you have specified on the grid container with:

```
grid-template-rows: 3.7rem auto auto
```

Once you remove the `height` rule, the overlap is gone.

```css
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 3.7rem auto auto;
 grid-template-columns: 3rem 3fr 2fr;
}
*[role="banner"] {
 grid-row: 1;
 grid-column: 2/4;
 
 background-color: green;
 height: 3rem;
}
*[role="main"] {
 grid-row: 2;
 grid-column: 2;
 background-color: yellow;
 /* height: 100px; <-------- REMOVE */
}
*[role="contentinfo"] {
 grid-row: 3;
 grid-column: 2/3;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
}
*[role="contentinfo"] img {
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div role="banner"></div>
<article role="main"><p>Some Text.</p><p>Some more text</p><p>the last text</p></article>
<footer role="contentinfo"><img src="https://s14-eu5.ixquick.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.motor-talk.de%2Fdata%2Fgalleries%2F0%2F147%2F9424%2F43109894%2Fbild--7008737403287221413.jpg&sp=6a4eaf3bd8ff58ca9d9bba2e3519888e"></footer>
```